# I am trying to get current location coordinates using GoogleClientApi, i am getting successful results in all devices except few micromax phones

Tags: locationmanager, google-client

In most of the devices i am getting successful results except few micromax phones. I tried both the ways using GoogleClientApi and LocationManager but getLastLocation() method is returning null. I updated google play services to the latest version. Device model : Micromax A110

Comment: Can you confirm if Micromax supports GPS? Basically not all phone have GPS or maybe they are currently disabled. Another thing GoogleClientApi does not support all kinds of Android Device like the Amazon Kindle even if it has GPS.

Comment: yes it supports, i checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Outdated version of Google Play Services. After updation, it is working fine!!